# How synchronization 2 SPList with workflow?

Tags: workflow, splistitem, splist

User add item to `SPList` 'one'. How do we add it item in `SPList` 'two with workflow?

NB: SPList on different servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both lists are same, you can use SharePoint designer workflow to copy list item from one list to other.

Below link may help you to get started:
http://blogs.salmanghani.info/copy-item-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Comment: It work's when 2 lists on one server. How do this when we have 2 lists on 2 separate servers?

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: You can try CSOM. On google search for CSOM for Console application. This will give you idea on how to connect to sharepoint site from remote machine. So from your source server you can connect to destination sharepoint site and add list item there.

Comment: This is just thought. I have not tried this.